# Can't deploy my app to github-pages with react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

I've recently finished building my app, using react-create-app, but I can't load it on github pages. It builds a production version without any problems, but whenever I enter "npm run deploy" into the console I get the following error:

> Error: spawn git ENOENT
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:1033:11)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:425:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:146:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:540:3

I'll leave a link to my package.json since I can't seem to make it look neat here: https://github.com/Umbrella1234/movie-app/blob/master/package.json
Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: It looks like the deploy command can't find `git` on your machine. Does it work from the console?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, make sure you have installed [Git for Windows from here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Considering you have taken the previous steps correctly, after installing Git for Windows, running `npm run deploy` creates an optimized production build and deploy it on GitHub pages. If you haven't logged in to Github for windows app before, Github app pops up and asks you to enter your username and password. When you've done that the deploy process will continue and uploads the production build on GitHub pages.

Comment: If you think the question is a duplicate, then raise a flag for attention for that. But you don't post a link to your existing answer as an answer to another question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Windows Powershell or even 3rd-Party software have trouble integrating with git.

One solution is to use `Git Bash` or whichever tool you know has works when trying to make commits. Navigate to the app directory using `cd` and then type `npm run deploy` inside of git bash. This should be able to connect to github no problem and fix your error.